# Linking error with mingw32 g++

Tags: g++, mingw

Why do I get:

```
undefined reference to `CryptAcquireContext(unsigned int**, char const*, char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)@20'
```

I am using the Mingw32 compiler suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some code is surely in order here. Otherwise, the only thing we can surmise is that the linker is unable to find a suitable definition of the `CryptAcquireContext` function (which may be due to a missing reference to the `Advapi32.lib` file).

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work, I think with -ladvapi32 or something like that in the Makefile.